# Apple software: moving Mail to an older computer

Tags: macos, mail.app

My Macbook Pro under Sierra needs repair. While it is being repaired, I am reverting to an old machine running Yosemite. Does anyone know if the format of Apple Mail files has changed between Yosemite and Sierra?

My idea is to copy Library/Mail from the machine for repair to the Yosemite machine. Will that work? Are there other files (for Apple Mail) that I should copy before taking it to the repair shop? Presumably plist files should not be copied over.

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved mail from Sierra to El-Capitan and it worked fine. There are no reported problems with the scenario you're describing. I'd suggest following this Apple Doc before sending your mac for repair and check that everything is working, though.

[Mail for Mac: Import or export mailboxes](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22318?locale=en_US)